# How to embed any *.jpg image inside win32 executable and use it at run time

Tags: c++, image, opengl, resources, soil

I am doing a project in pure OpenGL and FREEGLUT named [Space Voyager](https://github.com/sohailchd/SpaceVoyager). Problem is that during run time when programe calls a function to load all the images player has to wait around 2 minutes on loading screen!!!! Some of the images are like 16 MB files otherwise 1 MB in average. There are like 20 images in all. I need to load all the images before staring the level.

Now I am using [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) for loading the images in my game. SOIL has a function to load images from memory SOIL_load_OGL_texture_load_from_memory( unsigned char *image_in_RAM ,...).

My solution is to embed all the images in *.exe file of the game and use it at run time so as to save the time to load all the images in game.

I am pretty much lost as how to exactly embed the jpg images in executable and
use it at run time as unsigned char* imagePointer ?????

Comment: Have you profiled your code to check that the loading is the bottleneck in your app?

Comment: You might use .tga files instead of .jpg ? This is a format designed to textures. It is heavier on your disk, because files are usually larger than .jpg, but it loads slightly faster.

Comment: The logic seems shaky that the same data will load from disk to memory faster if it's in an "exe" file.

Comment: See LoadResource and related stuff. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I don't see how this would be any faster. The data still needs to be loaded from disk, and the JPG (or whatever format) still needs to be decoded. It's just coming from a different place on disk ...

Comment: I guess embedding jpgs within executable is not correct solution to the problem. I got the point here. I need to create some multithread resource loader just too save some time on loading screen.    THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My solution is to embed all the images in *.exe file of the game and use it at run time so as to save the time to load all the images in game.

How do you suppose this would do the trick? It doesn't matter what label the data on the storage device has on it. The effort for the computer system are invariant. It doesn't matter if you place the resources in a separate file to the computer it makes no difference whatsoever.

> Some of the images are like 16 MB files otherwise 1 MB in average. There are like 20 images in all. I need to load all the images before staring the level.

That's not a lot of data. 20 images with 1MiB in average, that's 20MiB in average. Even slow HDD disks of spinning rust can deliver 10MiB/s easily. A much more common figure is something like 50MiB to 80MiB/s for cheap HDDs these days. Wherever your bottleneck lies, it's not I/O.

Also keep in mind that if you embedded the files RAW into the executable you're forcing the system to shove more data through I/O; having the images compressed in the executable still requires you to decompress. Given the fact that most of the time you're I/O bound and not CPU bound having compressed images in storage is desireable.

#### UPDATE

Your problem is this:

[SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO](https://github.com/sohailchd/SpaceVoyager/blob/master/SpaceVoyager/TextureLoader.cpp#L29)

You're asking soil to rescale each and every image to the next bigger size that's a power of 2. Before OpenGL-2 this had to be done, since OpenGL-1 would only accept power-of-2 sized images for textures. Ever since OpenGL-2 came out (and you'll be hard pressed to find a GPU that doesn't support OpenGL-2 these days), that constraint has been lifted.

Another time consuming operation is the generation of mipmaps (SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS) since this required the generation of a whole image pyramid for each image. Now mipmapping is something you generally want to have. In case you have a context >=OpenGL-3 you can use the OpenGL built in mipmap generator. Also you're asking SOIL to generate texture IDs for you, but you also generate IDs yourself. Use either one, but don't use both.

This leads to the following suggested changes in your code:

```
while( GL_NO_ERROR != glGetError() ); // flush OpenGL errors;
GLint gl_version;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &gl_version);
if( GL_NO_ERROR != glGetError() ) {
    // GL_MAJOR_VERSION enum supported only since OpenGL-3
    gl_version = 1;
    while( GL_NO_ERROR != glGetError() ); // flush OpenGL errors;
}
bool const gl3_or_later = 3 <= gl_version;

tex_id = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(
        fileNameConstant,
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        gl3_or_later ? 0 : SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS );
if( gl3_or_later ) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_id);
    glGenerateTextureMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexParameteri(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
        GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL,
        1000);
}
```

Comment: Actually go all the required images amounts to exactly 167 MB. I am trying to load them before the game level starts. I need to use another thread to load the resources. Hopefully I may be able to save some of the time spent on loading screen. !!!! Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask you , Is there any method to load and link any pre compiled object code at run time. Anything close to that or something??

Comment: @Sohail_CHD: What does it matter that it's object code? Yes, you could place the image data into object code, but what purpose does it serve. All you get is a file with a slightly different structure, but the workload getting the image to the GPU does not change! For the computer it makes absolutely no difference! You have to understand this deep down in your guts: **There is no difference between code and data!** Data is code and code is data. Yes you could slap the images into a PE and throw `LoadLibrary` / `dlopen` at it, but behind the scenes it boils down to opening and reading a file.

Comment: @Sohail_CHD: 167MiB are not terribly much data. Even with a slow HDD this would load in under 4s. The issue you have at hand is, that SOIL is probably not the most efficient image loader there is. Also generating the mipmaps online is expensive. You'd gain much more if you would precompute the mipmaps. *DON'T BOTHER WITH TRYING TO PACK UP THE IMAGES DIFFERENTLY!* it won't do anything good. Instead look at more efficient JPEG loaders (TurboJPEG, libjpeg-turbo). Also memory mapping can help, but if you have to keep the while file in memory for decoding anyway, a simple read works just as well.

Comment: Never learn so much so quickly. Great pieces of advice. I will do away with SOIL and try something as you suggested. vielen Dank !!!

Comment: @Sohail_CHD: In case the question is not about using object code for images, but for dynamically loading program logic. Well, compile it to a DLL/so and use LoadLibrary/dlopen. Although for a game you normally want something like an embeddable scripting language that does JIT compilation. I suggest you look at Lua (http://www.lua.org) or Squirrel (http://squirrel-lang.org).

Comment: @Sohail_CHD: Just to give you an idea what's possible: The software I write for a living is dealing with image data in the order of several GiB (Gigabytes) and I can comfortably load and view a 35GiB dataset practically instantantly (by avoiding to load the whole thing completely and instead read the required parts on demand).